# How to select Channels to get their ID from a bot [tgbotapi]

Tags: go, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm creating a menu to help retrieve Channels IDs in golang. Very much like this bot: https://t.me/username_to_id_bot

[image: username_to_id_bot select channel screenshot]

The only info I could find to achieve this was using

```
https://t.me/[bot_username]?startchannel
```

This indeed open a select channel dialog but only the ones the user is admin and the prompt asks me if I want to add the bot to the channel. According to the [docs](https://core.telegram.org/api/links#groupchannel-bot-links), this is used to add the bot to the group/channel. I'm not really interested in that, specially in channels where a user not admin cannot write there to run any command.

```
    tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardRow(
        tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardButtonURL("Channel", "https://t.me/[mybotusername]?startchannel"),
    ),
)
```

How can I accomplish exactly the same as username_to_id bot? It would be nice to use normal buttons as username_to_id does instead of using inline keyboard but it seems this is the only way to accomplish this with this [api](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5)

This is the most I could accomplish:

[image]
[image]